# Add dictionary values for common keys based on categorical variables in another column

Tags: python, dictionary, text, group-by, counter

I am trying to add multiple dictionaries (sum of common keys), based on categorical variable in another column. I tried using the groupby (and agg), groupby (and sum), and Counter(). I have other continous columns too, but I do not want to add them up. I keep getting errors or undesired output.

```
import pandas as pd       
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter

# input
df1 = pd.DataFrame([
['Cat1', {'Word1': 8, 'Word2': 7, 'Word3': 6, 'Word4':1}], 
['Cat2', {'Word2': 7, 'Word4': 7, 'Word3': 6}], 
['Cat2', {'Word3':3, 'Word5': 2}],
['Cat1', {'Word1': 10, 'Word3': 5, 'Word4':1}]], columns=list('AB'))



# desired output
df_out = pd.DataFrame([
['Cat1', {'Word1': 18, 'Word2': 7, 'Word3': 11, 'Word4':2}],
['Cat2', {'Word2': 7, 'Word3': 9, 'Word4': 7, 'Word5': 2}]], columns=list('AB'))
df_out

# Trial 1 - groupby
for i in range(len(df1)):
    df1.groupby('A')['B'].agg({df1['B'][i])

# Trial 2 - Counter
counter = Counter()
for d in range(len(df['B']):
    counter.update(d)
```

Any help is appreciated. TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution which produces a regular DataFrame instead of a Series of dicts:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_records(df1.B).groupby(df1.A).sum()
```

The first step converts your Series of dicts into a regular DataFrame with one column per key.  Then it's a simple groupby and sum to get the final result:

```
      Word1  Word2  Word3  Word4  Word5
A                                      
Cat1   18.0    7.0     11    2.0    0.0
Cat2    0.0    7.0      9    7.0    2.0
```

Keeping your data in such a format will be much more efficient than a Series of dicts, unless the values are very sparse (i.e. the matrix is large and mostly zeros).

If you do need the result to be a Series of dicts, this works:

```
def add_dicts(s):
    c = Counter()
    s.apply(c.update)
    return dict(c)

df1.groupby('A').B.agg(add_dicts)
```

It produces exactly your `df_out`.

Comment: Thank you so much. Unfortunately, the text manipulation I am trying is for 3000+ rows and each dictionary having more than 500 different key:value pairs. Is there anything else you would recommend in that case?

Comment: @erm0rden: I suggest trying both of the solutions I wrote here (perhaps you didn't see the second one yet because I added it later), and see which one performs better.  I'd be curious to know which solution you choose.

Comment: The second solutions works perfect! I need to keep the dictionary intact for further operations.Thanks a lot :)